# How to change table cell background color using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the background color of the cell based on its text contents using jquery.

Example:

For the second row in the "Exceeds" td, I want to change the background color to green because it has Exceeds as it's text...

```
<table>    
<tr><td>Jedi Armor1</td><td>Needs</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jedi Armor2</td><td>Exceeds</td></tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: You could do this in CSS if it's an option. Simply do `table tr td:nth-child(2) { ... }`

Comment: ..and you want this based on the contents of the cell...or it's position in the table? AND you want to change the whole **column** or just that cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to change the color of the cell and only the cell. If you want to change the color of it based on its text, use the [contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) jQuery selector :

CSS :

```
.greenBg {
    background: green;
}
```

jQuery :

```
$("td:contains('Exceeds')").addClass('greenBg');
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/5wvwC/)**

**Edit :**

If you want to restrict this to the second column only, this would be more suited :

```
$("td:nth-child(2):contains('Exceeds')").addClass('greenBg');
```

In case someone would want to change the color of the whole column :

```
$("td:nth-child(2):contains('Exceeds')").closest('table').find('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('greenBg');
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/kLSn8/)**

Comment: I'm actually not sure of what the OP want... The question is not really clear !

Comment: Well it's certainly clear (from other comments) that **something** is based on the word "Exceeds" but, as you say, it's unclear **what** !

Answer (score 3):

**Update Following Question Clarification:**

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/f5WqV/6/)

To change the background color of one cell based on the value of another, you can use e.g:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function () {
    $(this).text() == 'Exceeds' && $(this).parent().find('td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

---

To change the background of a specific column:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

However you should try to maintain the seperation of styles by using CSS, in which case you can accomplish this with:

```
table tr td:nth-child(2){
  /* styles*/
}
```

Or..if you specifically need dynamic control, instead of allocating the style directly in jQuery, add a class:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').addClass('rowBackground');
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.rowBackground{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Wait how about the logic for the text?

Answer (score 3):

Native JS:

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var i = 0, tds = td.length;
for (i; i < tds; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerHTML == "Exceeds") {
        td[i].setAttribute("style", "background:green;");
    }
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/vHvLh/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.eq()` or `:eq()` selector:

```
$('table tr td:eq(3)').css('background-color','green');
```

or use `.last()` if the `td` that you want to change the color is always the last `td`:

```
$('table tr td').last().css('background-color','green')
```